# How do I set up a Gatsby website to work with Netlify?

Tags: gatsby

I am trying to set up a website using Gatsby, but then want to deploy it and allow others to edit it, using Netlify.

I am going through [the tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-zero/) on how to set up a project.

```
gatsby new raven https://gatsby-starter-netlify-cms
```

I get the following (much longer, but it's a snippet):

```
In file included from In file included from ../../nan/nan.h../../nan/nan.h::27222722:
:
../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h::2424::2525::  errorerror: : no member named 'IsNearDeath' in 'Nan::Persistent<v8::Object, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object> >'
no member named 'IsNearDeath' in 'Nan::Persistent<v8::Object, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object> >'
    assert(persistent().IsNearDeath());
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
    assert(persistent().IsNearDeath());
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/assert.h           ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^:
93:25: note: expanded from macro 'assert'/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/assert.h


... 

fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
1 warning and 20 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:200:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.3.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/timfong/raven/node_modules/sharp
gyp ERR! node -v v12.3.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN gatsby-starter-netlify-cms@1.1.3 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sharp@0.21.3 install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.21.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
error Command failed: npm install
```

I copied the URL from the web page of starters

Comment: Have you successfully made it through the `Set Up Your Development Environment` section of the tutorial?